# Loop through multiple inputs and save the answer to a variable using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So far, I have:

```
$('.the-inputs input').each(function() {
    userAnswer = $(this).val();
});
```

However, if I `console.log` this out, it comes out on separate lines (is this an array?) I would like it as a string.

So, if the user enters "Hello" "World" in the two inputs, I want the variable `userAnswer = "Hello World"`.

I also need the variable accessible outside the function. Am I right in leaving off the `var` to achieve this?

Comment: declare userAnswer global and concatenate

Comment: The each function of a jQuery object will run the callback function you define once for every element that matches the selector you input. That is why you received separate lines in the console log

Comment: the `var` declaration only determines wether its a global variable or only in the functionscope. Either way, each illitaration of the each-loop will overwrite it to `$(this).val()`

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the var thing. I completely get that now. Also, I know what the jQuery is doing, I just don't know how to achieve what I want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var userAnswer = '';

$('.the-inputs input').each(function() {
 userAnswer += $(this).val() + ' '; // add to string
});

userAnswer = $.trim(userAnswer);

console.log(userAnswer);
```

Comment: This has worked perfectly apart from one thing, the console brings up undefined right before the string. So if I enter "foo" and "bar" into the inputs, I get `undefinedfoo bar` in the console... Why is this?

Comment: because in the first loop `userAnswer` is undefined (it has not been giving an value), and the other answers will stick to that. To fix it `var userAnswer = '';`. Now the first value will be an empty string

Comment: Interesting you added the $.trim method. Actually, I wanted the space between the answers, but it's good to know how to join them. Thanks!

Comment: The space between the anwsers will stay, I've added trim to remove last space that was added on last anwser.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to solve this:

```
var userAnswer = $('.the-inputs input').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get().join(' ');
```

Comment: simple and effective.

Comment: What would be the advantage of map vs each? I think the `each()` has a bit more readability, but I asume it has something to do with the way jQuery handles them.

Comment: Hmmm, this didn't work for me. I'm sure it's an effective way of doing it, but I get `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'join'` in the console...

Comment: @jpsear : check now. I have edited the answer. You have to call the `.get()` before calling the `.join()` function. Its mentioned in the documentation link that is mentioned in the answer . Demo http://jsfiddle.net/yrdFh/

Comment: Thanks, that indeed works well. What advantage does this have over the answer below (also works well)?

Comment: @jpsear both are same, this looks more jQuery-ish way

Comment: @ArunPJohny : Not an issue. Nice Answer btw